# Couldn't find sdl2.dll

Tags: c++, dll, mingw, command-prompt, sdl-2

I'm trying to use sdl2, but when I try to run my program it gives me an error that says

```
code execution can't proceed because SDL2.dll couldn't be found. try reinstalling [...]
```

I'm compiling from the terminal, without any IDEs (I'm writing code in Sublime Text). My command looks like this

```
g++ src\main.cpp -o ..\..\test.exe -L lib\sdl32\lib -l SDL2 -I lib\sdl32\inc -m32
```

and my file system like this

I tried putting the `.exe` file in the same directory as the `lib` files, but it doesn't work.

I thought the problem might be that it's looking for `SDL2.dll` files and all of them are `libSDL2.*` and I tried changing the file names but it didn't work.

I also thought the problem was the extension, because they are all in `*.dll.a`, `*.a` or `*.la`, I tried changing that and it didn't work (I also tried a combination of the two).

This is my `main.cpp`

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 450, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 255, 255);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing a file or a compiler flag or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libSDL2.dll.a` is an *import* library. You use it at compile-time to link the code to load the `.dll` into your binary. You will still need to have the `SDL2.dll` file at runtime which contains the actual implementation. On Windows, `.dll` files are searched in the `PATH`; the simplest way to use them is to put them in the directory that contains the executable.

The `.dll` file is available for download [on the SDL website](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php), you seem to only have the development files.

Comment: Development files include the .dll as well.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat True, still seemed to be missing in this case.